How to set up Cura plugin
When I was trying to learn how to build a plugin of my own, I took Marketplace in the plugins directory as an example to learn, and I wanted to know what steps Marketplace went through to show up in Cura.enter image description here
I changed the Button named "Markplace" to "MainWindowHeaderTest" in the MainWindowHeader.qml file.
I traced it down through onClicked and found that browsePackagesAction does not execute a function, but clicking on the "Markplace" Button will execute a function and bring up a window. I don't understand that there is no function triggered in the browsePackagesAction, but there is a function executed. Can anyone tell me why?
enter image description here
enter image description here
I would really appreciate if anyone could give me advice on how to debug some thing like this.
I would really appreciate if anyone could give me advice on how to debug some thing like this.

you need to fix your image embeds...
